# How do I make an unbalanced binary tree that branches off to the right?

Tags: diagrams, trees

An image of what I want:

[image: Imgur]

For those who are interested: This particular figure is taken from [this article](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45748-8_5) (I couldn't find a freely available version) and shows *k-buckets* (the squares) covering an increasingly larger prefix of a binary ID space.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could come up with a suggestion to how I can make this type of tree:

- Each leaf is a bucket/square
- Only the leaves have buckets.
- The tree branches off to the right, leaving each branch half the amount of space as the previous

### Edit

I've tweaked some of the numbers in Gonzalo Medina's brilliant answer a little bit to come closer to exactly what I want, but I have to confess that I have no idea what's going on and how the code work.

What I would like now is to make the tree wider so that the boxes don't overlap on the vertical axis.

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north},
s sep=30pt,
[
  [,draw,text width=4cm,edge label={node[midway,left=12pt]{$1$}}]
  [,shape=coordinate,edge label={node[midway,right=10pt]{$0$}}
    [,draw,text width=2cm,edge label={node[midway,left=4pt]{$1$}}]
    [,shape=coordinate,s sep=-\pgflinewidth,edge label={node[midway,right=4pt]{$0$}}
      [,draw,text width=0.5cm,edge label={node[midway,left]{$1$}}]
      [,draw,text width=0.5cm,edge label={node[midway,right]{$0$}}]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
```

[image: Imgur]

Also, where would I put it if I wanted text inside some of the boxes?

Comment: @Jubobs I scrapped what I had and went with what Gonzalo Medina provided; question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north},
s sep=30pt,
[
  [,draw,text width=3cm,edge label={node[midway,left=4pt]{$0$}}]
  [,shape=coordinate,edge label={node[midway,right]{$1$}}
    [,draw,text width=2cm,edge label={node[midway,left]{$0$}}]
    [,shape=coordinate,s sep=-\pgflinewidth,edge label={node[midway,right]{$1$}}
      [,draw,text width=1cm,edge label={node[midway,left]{$0$}}]
      [,draw,text width=1cm,edge label={node[midway,right]{$1$}}]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the values for `l`, `l sep` (for vertical distance), `s sep` (for horizontal distance) you can change the tree geometry (please refer to the package documentation for an explanation about those keys). A little example::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north},
for tree={l =-0ex}
[,s sep=3cm
  [,draw,text width=3cm,edge label={node[midway,above left=0pt]{$0$}}]
  [,s sep=1.5cm,shape=coordinate,edge label={node[midway,above right]{$1$}}
    [,draw,text width=2cm,edge label={node[midway,left=8pt]{$0$}}]
    [,shape=coordinate,s sep=-\pgflinewidth,edge label={node[midway,right=8pt]{$1$}}
      [,draw,text width=1cm,edge label={node[midway,left=6pt]{$0$}}]
      [,draw,text width=1cm,edge label={node[midway,right=6pt]{$1$}}]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the boxes should have text, it's better to define a style for them to make sure all will have the same height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
myempty/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  minimum height=16pt,
  anchor=north
  }
}

\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north},
for tree={l =2ex}
[,s sep=1cm
  [texta,myempty=3cm,edge label={node[midway,above left=0pt]{$0$}}]
  [,s sep=1cm,shape=coordinate,edge label={node[midway,above right]{$1$}}
    [textb,myempty=2cm,edge label={node[midway,left=8pt]{$0$}}]
    [,shape=coordinate,s sep=-\pgflinewidth,edge label={node[midway,right=8pt]{$1$}}
      [textc,myempty=1cm,edge label={node[midway,left=6pt]{$0$}}]
      [textd,myempty=1cm,edge label={node[midway,right=6pt]{$1$}}]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful! Do you happen to know how I can space it out a little more (make it wider and/or flatter) but hold back the width of the boxes?

Comment: @Daniero Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Wow, you responded so quickly that I didn't have time to properly update the question :)

Comment: @Daniero Please see my updated answer (adding text inside the boxes).